# Niumpy : Convert numpy 2d array to 3d

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I'm trying to build a neural network and I have this input training array. I print out the shape of the array.

```
print(dataX_lstm.shape)
print(dataX_lstm[0].shape)
print(dataX_lstm[0][0].shape)
```

This is the result:

```
(455, 4)
(4,)
(36,)
```

So, now I can see that the outer numpy array just sees the data as 2d matrix, and that the 2nd dimension each represents a numpy array. I need to convert to a 3d array of 455 * 4 * 36.(Note: every array has 36 columns so it shouldn't be a problem). Is there any way I could do this?

Comment: Please give some reproducible code, so a short example

Comment: Normally if all the data types are the same, it would be automatically a 3D-array. So could you please post the types which are held by the different arrays?

Comment: You don't show how you constructed `dataX_lstm` but the mix of shapes suggests that inner arrays vary in shape. `dataX_lstm[i,j[.shape` is not the same for all `i,j`.  Also what's the dtype(s)?